# How can I determine where to show a nameplate over a character?

Tags: c#, unity

I'm working on a naming system that displays the name of enemies above their heads.

The problem is that I have some enemies that are larger or smaller than others. So I'm trying to use a function that gets the height of the enemy, and then uses that as the modifier for the name's position.

Here's what I'm doing (I should mention that the `target` is the enemy that is currently being targeted):

```
public Vector3 offset = Vector3.up;
...
thisTransform.position = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position + offset);
```

What I'd like to do:

```
public float enemyHeight;
...
enemyHeight = target.collider.bounds.size.y + .5f;
thisTransform.position = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(target.position + enemyHeight);
```

But obviously it is giving me an error that I can't add a float to a vector. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the nameplate position (in world space), start with the character's origin (in world space). Hopefully your character origins are defined such that they represent the center of the character on the ground, since that's the meaning that makes the most sense in general. If your character origins are something else, you'll need to account for that.

Then, compute the character height plus some offset to allow for the padding between the top of the character and the nameplate. As you've noted, this is a floating point value. You can't add a float and a vector, but you can add two vectors, so if you simply construct a vector `(0, height + padding, 0)` and add that to the origin of the character, you'll have your nameplate origin.

This assumes, of course, Y is up in your world, but that is similarly easy to adjust for. If however "up" isn't always the same (for example if a character can stand on a 45-degree inline) you will instead want to construct the offset vector in a more general fashion. One way to do this is to take the normal vector of the plane the character is standing in (which should be normalizing it) and *scaling* that vector by the character height and offset. This also produces a vector you can add to the origin.

This gives you the nameplate position in world space, which you can use directly or project to screen space if you need to. In some cases it may be more desirable to instead project the bounding box of the character to screen space, find it's highest Y position and use that (plus some offset) as the basis for the nameplate. Both methods (and many others) are valid, it depends primarily on what sort of effect and behavior you want out of the nameplate.